# Lucene check index size

Tags: c#, lucene

Is there any way to check Lucene index size in the Lucene API? I mean other than going to FSDirectory.getDirectory and "manually" checking file size for every file in the directory?
Thanks!

Maxim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no method to get index size, but instead of getting all files in directory you should grab file list with IndexReader :

```
    IndexReader ir = IndexReader.Open(FDirectory);
    foreach(string fName in ir.Directory().List())
    {
      // sum file sizes here
    }
    ir.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I used 
var size = (from strFile in dir.ListAll()
                          select dir.FileLength(strFile)).Sum();

where dir is Lucene.Net.Store.Directory where the index was created.. Seems good enough..

Maxim